# Why was my question closed as a bug report and as already being solved when non of those are the case?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I believe that [one of my question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/593233/crash-when-creating-new-vm-with-virtualbox-but-no-obvious-change-in-cpu-memory) was recently wrongly closed, because it says it was closed for the following reasons:

[image]

However, it is not a bug report, nor a problem with a specific development version of Ubuntu, and the problem described **can** still be reproduced, so why was my question closed?

Comment: Have you considered reporting a bug?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Braiam kicked off the process (as he describes below). That got it into the review process. What followed was an assumption that it was abandoned.

The OT-Bug reason isn't explicit about the exact problem —a failure in itself— so where not obviously a development issue, I'd certainly expect somebody to clarify their reasoning. Closing might be helpful to us, commenting is helpful to the person with the problem. It also helps assuage situations like this.

Failure all around. I've re-opened.

Comment: **This is a bug behavior**. I did not look to the date or the version. I repeat, do not ever presume my intentions or behavior. **YOU GET IT WRONG**. This needs to be addressed by developers that know how to debug this issue, not users.

Comment: @Braiam Sure. But if your intentions are so consistently misread, leave a comment or two. Consider what is best for the person with the problem, not just Ask Ubuntu. (It would also help following reviewers understand.)

Comment: The close reason is there to capture my intentions, and if it cannot do that task maybe a rewording is necessary.

Comment: @Braiam There is the custom close reason of course.

Answer (score 3):

[I've left a comment explaining my position](https://askubuntu.com/questions/593233/crash-when-creating-new-vm-with-virtualbox-but-no-obvious-change-in-cpu-memory#comment1080172_593233) of what you should do to solve your issue. **Ask Ubuntu is not designed to solve/report bugs**. I wasn't the only user that through that it was a bug, 2 other users agreed and two others through you already didn't have the behavior (though no evidence of such is given).

I see that unless I'm commenting on all questions I close nobody would ever guess my intentions. Instead of assuming my intentions and acting on those assumptions, **ask me instead**.